# Expression arrange by base

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression with multiple powers, for example

```
N^α/(B*N)^β
```

Any simplification like `FullSimplify` leads to

$$ N^\alpha (NB)^{-\beta}$$

How do I separate the different bases? I want to have the expression organized like

$$ N^{\alpha - \beta} B^{-\beta} $$

and in a more complicated expression with many different bases, I want them all separated. None of the functions described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingExpressionsIntoDifferentForms.html) is suitable for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expr = n^a/(n*b)^c;
expr // PowerExpand

(*  b^-c n^(a - c)   *)
```

Do not use the capital `N` since in Mma it is a service word.

Have fun!

Comment: I do **not** want to have the the terms sorted by powers, but rather by bases - this appears not to do what I want.

Comment: I do not see any difference between the result and the form you wish up to Mma internal ordering. The latter is out of reach, unless you use the functions of the `Hold` group.

Comment: You don't see a difference in the ordering between $N^{\alpha - \beta} B^{-\beta}$ and $N^\alpha (NB)^{-\beta}$?

Comment: No, I do not see the difference between `b^-c n^(a - c) ` that I obtained and `n^(a - c) b^-c ` that you wish.